# How can I dynamically post Request body (xml) and validate the response (xml)?

Tags: jmeter

Is there a way to send the XML request dynamically and validate the XML response?

My scenario is:
I will have a CSV dataset config and inside the csv file I will have two column, the first one is for the inputXMLFilePath and the second column is the expectedXMLResposneFilePath.

So I need to have a JSR233 PreProcessor under HTTP request sampler, read the input file path convert it to the post body, and also has another JSR233 sampler for load the expected response from the expectedXMLResponseFilePath and compare it with the previous XML response. I have a snippet for JSON which is working fine. but for XML how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function for both use cases:

1. To send the XML request body, like `${__FileToString(${inputXMLFilePath},,)}` (where `${inputXMLFilePath}` is the variable from the CSV Data Set Config)

   [image: JMeter Send Request Body From File]
2. To validate the response using [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) configured like:

   - Field to Test: `Text Response`
   - Pattern Matching Rules: `Equals`
   - Patterns to test: `${__FileToString(${expectedXMLResponseFilePath},,)}`

     [image: JMeter FileToString in Assertion]

You can use JMeter Functions literally at the any place of your [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) so their flexibility is higher than for other test elements. Also JMeter Functions are being compiled into native Java code therefore their execution speed will be higher and footprint will be less comparing to Groovy scripting.

Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article to learn more about JMeter Functions concept.

Comment: Thanks, Dmitri, it works. I will go over that article again :)